# Cannot update or delete many in ReactiveMongo 0.16

Tags: json, scala, reactivemongo, bulkupdate

I'm having some difficulty with `delete.many` and `update.many` using the new *builders* whilst trying to convert my previous version's (working) code into reactivemongo 0.16.5 (`"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.16.5-play26", "org.reactivemongo" %% "reactivemongo-akkastream" % "0.16.5"`. As you'll see; I'm using this within the Play plugin so dealing with JSON (rather than BSON)

I'm going from [the official documentation here](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/release-details.html#query-and-write-operations). My errors are similar for both `update` & `delete` so I'll just post for `update` here to keep it trim.

**Update command**

```
    def updateMany(collName: String)(quJsa: JsArray)(orderedBool: Boolean = false): Future[MultiBulkWriteResult] = {

        lazy val updateBuilder = getCollection(collName).map(_.update(orderedBool))

        quJsa.asOpt[Seq[JsObject]].map(
          _.map(
            x => x.as[MongoUpdateBuilder]
          )
        ).map(
          _.map(
            x => updateBuilder.flatMap(
              _.element(q = x.q, u = x.getSetUpdate, upsert = x.upsertBool, multi = x.multiBool)
            )
          )
        ).map(
          x => Future.sequence(x)
        ).map(
          _.flatMap(
            x => updateBuilder.flatMap(
              _.many(x)
            )
          )
        ).getOrElse(getMultiBulkWriteResultErrorF("input not recognised as jsarr"))

    }
```

**Custom update builder model**

```
    case class MongoUpdateBuilder(q: JsObject, u: JsObject, upsertBool: Boolean, multiBool: Boolean) {
        def getSetUpdate = Json.obj("$set" -> u)
    }

    object MongoUpdateBuilder {
        implicit val mongoUpdateBuilderFormat = Json.format[MongoUpdateBuilder]
}
```

**Error container**

```
      def getMultiBulkWriteResultErrorF(errStr: String): Future[MultiBulkWriteResult] = {

        val mbwr = MultiBulkWriteResult(
          ok = false,
          n = 0,
          nModified = 0,
          upserted = Seq(),
          writeErrors = Seq(WriteError(index = 0, code = 404, errmsg = errStr)),
          writeConcernError = None,
          code = Some(404),
          errmsg = Some(errStr),
          totalN = 0
        )

        Future.successful(mbwr)
      }
```

And the main issue:

> no type parameters for method flatMap: (f: reactivemongo.play.json.collection
>   .JSONCollection#UpdateBuilder => scala.concurrent.Future[S])(implicit executor: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext)scala.concurrent.Future[S] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (reactivemongo.play.json.collection.JSONCollection#UpdateBuilder => scala.concurrent.Future[_1.UpdateCommand.UpdateElement] forSome { val _1: reactivemongo.play.json.collection.J
>   SONCollection }) [error]  --- because ---
>   [error] argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
>   [error]  found   : reactivemongo.play.json.collection.JSONCollection#UpdateBuilder => scala.concurrent.Future[_1.UpdateCommand.UpdateElement] forSome { val _1: reactivemongo.play.jso
>   n.collection.JSONCollection }
>   [error]  required: reactivemongo.play.json.collection.JSONCollection#UpdateBuilder => scala.concurrent.Future[?S]
>   [error]         x => updateBuilder.flatMap(

So the issue seems to be this line - `updateBuilder.flatMap`. The `Future` cannot be `flattened` with these types (`JSONCollection#UpdateBuilder` & `JSONCollection#UpdateCommand.UpdateElement`). So I'm struggling with this one. Please reach out if you can see the issue here. Many thanks!

Comment: Pimping w/ a custom query builder is not recommended, and will not be possible in next major release.

Comment: @cchantep I'm just trying to follow the 0.16.5 write commands [http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/release-details.html#query-and-write-operations#update](documented here) -  only I'm using the _Play JSON plugin_ as mentioned

Comment: JSON or BSON doesn't change anything, as both are provided serialization.

Comment: @cchantep So can this be done in 0.16.5 or no? If not then I don't understand why its on the release notes. I'm not sure what you mean by "pimping w/ a custom query builder". The `getCollection` function is `def getCollection(collName: String): Future[JSONCollection] = database.map(_.collection[JSONCollection](collName))` so this becomes a `Future[JSONCollection#UpdateBuilder]`. How else should we update with multiple queries in 0.16.5 then?

Comment: I feel there is misunderstanding and/or mix of concern: neither JSON serialization nor bulk ops require pimping query builder with a custom one (which is anyway over engineered, and there probably root cause of the issue)

Comment: @cchantep There is most definitely a misunderstanding. I don't know how else to create the command other than `val updateBuilder = database.map(_.collection[JSONCollection](collName).update(orderedBool))`. Never heard of the term "pimping" in this context. A workable example with JSON might cut the confusion down

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo-Play-Json/blob/master/src/test/scala/JSONCollectionSpec.scala#L78

Comment: @cchantep I know how to update with one query - I'm trying to bulk update. It's done [here in mongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodbs-new-bulk-api)

Comment: Just replace by [`.many`](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/blob/master/driver/src/main/scala/api/collections/UpdateOps.scala#L93)

Comment: @cchantep But I still need to create the `Iterable[UpdateElement]` since `final def many(updates: Iterable[UpdateElement])`. Unfortunately it doesn't take `Seq[JsObject]` like the `insertBuilder`. So I was attempting to do that with the `updateBuilder` per the [ReactiveMongo 0.16.6 – Release details](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/release-details.html#query-and-write-operations) as previously mentioned. I've updated to `ReactiveMongo 0.16.6` since the original post but no solutions still.

Comment: The linked example show a `many` update using documents, and as said several time previously, documents can be BSON or JSON

Comment: @cchantep Yes I'm familiar with the [BSON to JSON conversions](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/json/overview.html#documents-and-values). I'm using these to create a `JSONCollection#UpdateBuilder` as you'll see from my original post & per the [release notes](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/release-details.html#query-and-write-operations). But again - the parameter of `many` (for the `update` command) is `Iterable[UpdateElement]`..

Comment: @cchantep And this is where I am getting the `type mismatch` error - `[error]  found   : Seq[reactivemongo.play.json.collection.JSONCollection with Singleton#UpdateCommand.UpdateElement]
[error]  required: Iterable[_1.UpdateCommand.UpdateElement] where val _1: reactivemongo.play.json.collection.JSONCollection`. I don't know how else to explain this.

Comment: You're example is not following the way it's done in the link. Try it first please.

Comment: http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/api/reactivemongo/api/collections/UpdateOps$UpdateBuilder.html#many(updates:Iterable[UpdateOps.this.UpdateCommand.UpdateElement])(implicitec:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[reactivemongo.api.commands.MultiBulkWriteResult]

Comment: @cchantep I am running 0.18.6 and am having the same issue. I copied word for word the example provided in "Update a document" section of http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/tutorial/write-documents.html.
I keep getting the compilation error of 
type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[reactivemongo.api.collections.bson.BSONCollection with Singleton#UpdateCommand.UpdateElement]

 required: Iterable[_1.UpdateCommand.UpdateElement] where val _1: reactivemongo.api.collections.bson.BSONCollection